# How to provide space from left and right in navbar's content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want develop a `navbar` which content has space from left and right and it should support mobile, desktop screen side too, but I am unable to get it.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eNno</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portifolio</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the output of my code

[image]

How can I get it

Comment: you can use `margin-left` and `margir-right`

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov - Then again I have menus far left and I want to support mobile screen too so using margin will destroy it. There must be something to do it in a good way

Comment: Replace `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">` to `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`

Comment: `<ul class="navbar-nav">` remove `mr-auto` and add `margin-left: 35vw;`

Comment: @RayeesAC - I need margin for brand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a [Bootstrap `.container`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#containers) inside your `<nav>`. This will set the proper margins to the left and right. In addition, change `navbar-nav mr-auto` to `navbar-nav ml-auto` to align your navbar items to the right.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eNno</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portifolio</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This result looks like this:

[image: Resulting navbar]

The mobile navbar:

[image: Resulting mobile navbar]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said I need for mobile application too. When I click on 3 lines in mobile screen menus are not opening. Could u pl help.

Comment: How should your mobile screen exactly look like? For the moment, it is just the basic Bootstrap mobile navbar.

Comment: There is no specific support just it should look good in small screen size(bootstrap already handling). When I reduce size of chrome browser, right side menus turns into humberger button. When I am clicking on that button menus are not opening. Try reducing browser size here. https://usebootstrap.com/preview-no-frame/enno/

Comment: It was a bug in my answer. I forgot about adding the required JavaScript files, but after @Rayees AC's edit, everything should work properly now. I will add a screenshot of the mobile navbar on the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Or are you trying to achieve the same result as displayed on usebootstrap.com/preview-no-frame/enno ?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code. Seems issue with long key(integrity) present in links. I am not using references that way. Let me check if I can fix with references in another way in visual studio code. Yes I need say way given in link

Comment: You can even remove the `integrity` keys and it should still work properly.